# Dynamically change the namespace SoapTypeAttribute

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

I have a problem with service references visual studio.

I have a client who gives me a WSDL file to work with php.
I made a reference to the service of his ClassLibrary wsdl in my project.
Below is a portion of the generated proxy code

`[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://127.0.0.1:88/webservices/wsdl")]
    public partial class loginReturn : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {`

My problem is that wsdl is can be installed on another server to a second client.
Thus the address of the wsdl is set in my app.config

I did a test by changing the server port error is encountered
My problem is the namespace of SoapTypeAttribute

`[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://127.0.0.1:88/webservices/wsdl")]`

How can change this attribute value according to the server address because i have this error

**Error deserializing body of reply message for operation 'getlogin'..**

for this method

```
loginReturn t =  service.Getlogin("username", "pwd");
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is the namespace defined in the wsdl? The namespace is unrelated to the url/endpoint of the webservice.

Comment: <definitions xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:si="http://soapinterop.org/xsd"
xmlns:tns="http://127.0.0.1:88/webservices/wsdl" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
targetNamespace="http://127.0.0.1:88/webservices/wsdl">
<types>
 sd:schema targetNamespace="http://127.0.0.1:88/webservices/wsdl">
……………..

Answer (score 0):

The attribute is being cause by this `"127.0.0.1:82/moodle/wspp/wsdl"` namesspace in your wsdl file.  This can be any value so long as it is unique, URLs are usually used. So long as this is the SAME on both servers, setting the URL on the proxy class for the web service should work. e.g.

```
MyMroxyClass.Url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyServiceURL"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

The problem was server side, not client side. My client regenerated the wsdl on each server, so the signature of the changed wsdl

Comment: could you provide some more information about the solving, i ran into the same problems! thank you in advance!